# Flutter change variable type from string to IconData

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, font-awesome

I have A database with fontAwesome Icon I want to fetch it from the backend and loading it into my App but FontAwesome only accept IconData type so how can I change the string to that type or if there is any other solution without changing the Database
this is My Database:

**Icons DataBase**
[image]

```
Row(
                    children:<Widget>[
                      FaIcon (FontAwesomeIcons.(Uri.dataFromString(dataList[index]["ICONE_SERVICE"]))),
                    ]// <Widget>[]

                ),// Row
```

I tried to use the Uri.dataFromString but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, you are using [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) package, right?

Comment: Yes  @Samuel I'm using [font_awesome_flutter 9.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your database you can create an extension to convert from string to IconData object

```dart
extension IconStringExt on String {
  IconData? get iconParse => {
    "fa fa-bus": FontAwesomeIcons.bus,
    "fa fa-car": FontAwesomeIcons.car,
  }[this];
}
```

And use it like this (with a default icon after the ?? operator when the conversion doesn't find an icon):

```dart
FaIcon(dataList[index]["ICONE_SERVICE"]?.iconParse ?? FontAwesomeIcons.question)
```

More about extensions in Dart: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

Comment: Thanks for reply but it give me this Error:
The getter 'iconParse' isn't defined for the class 'Uri'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'iconParse'.
                            FaIcon(Uri.dataFromString(dataList[index]["ICONE_SERVICE"]).iconParse ?? FontAwesomeIcons.question)
Where should I place the extesion I place it under this:
Class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

Comment: @MajdiZlitni , and if you remove `Uri.dataFromString()` and just use `dataList[index]["ICONE_SERVICE"].iconParse` ? You should get the string from table's column ICON_SERVICE and parse it as an icon